# Fatal error when installing a payment plugin Virtuemart 3.2

Tags: php, plugins, virtuemart

When we install our payment plugin from zip package, it doesn't work and shows a fatal error in our log files. We trace the error in the vmplugin.php file at line 69 "$this->loadJLangThis($filename); //TODO remove this is not allowed here, else systemplugins derived from vmPlugin throw errors on a multilanguage pages".

Is it possible that this function has not been removed by accident (as marked as TODO in the line's comment)?

We can trace further the error and see that the problem is in vmplugin.php in the function loadJLang($fname,$type,$name) at line 108 $tag = vmLanguage::$currLangTag;

```
//$jlang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    //$tag = $jlang->getTag();
    //if(empty($tag)) {
        $tag = vmLanguage::$currLangTag;
    //}
```

where $tag appears to be empty.

Can anybody help me with this problem, or tell me why $tag is empty? I would really appreciate any help.

Edit: The error log is:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/plugins/vmplugin.php on line 124, referer: /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer

Comment: What is the specific text of the fatal error? Not where you traced it to.

Comment: I edited my question with the error log